# I wrote a numpy array to csv using numpy.savetxt(), but the array looks different when I read it back using numpy.genfromtxt()

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, numpy, csv

I am working on my first machine learning model, and I have a data set from Kaggle. I did a lot of formatting and got the data set split into train/dev/test as numpy arrays. I wrote the training set numpy array to a csv format using numpy. The training set is a numpy array of dimensions 64x27226. However, when I read the training set back using numpy's genfromtxt() function, I get a (64,) dimensional array with all elements as NaNs.

I tried reading the csv with pandas but then pandas automatically sets the first row of the csv as the labels for the columns, and returns a (63,27226) dimensional DataFrame.

How can I fix this? [X_train and its dimensions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0SIrp.png)

[When I read the csv using pandas](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2VWgq.png)

[When I read the csv using numpy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lMtgd.png)

Comment: The default delimiter for `genfromtxt` is white space, not comma.  I'm guessing it reading each line, can't split it, or convert it to a number, and so sets that element to `nan`.  As for the pandas, you need to pay attention to headers.  Either way, you need to spend time looking at the documentation.

Answer (score 0):

To read the CSV with `pandas` without assigning the first row as a header you need to pass param `header=None`-

```py
df = pd.read_csv(file_name, header = None)
```

See the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html)

Answer (score 0):

You can read in the csv using `Pandas` which is almost always the best choice, and set `header` to None.
Also, since you're using a `numpy ndarray`, you probably want to stick with it. This will give you a numpy.ndarray:

```
import pandas
data = pandas.read_csv('file.csv', header = None).to_numpy()
```

[Docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy.html#pandas.DataFrame.to_numpy)